# How come when I run this program with more than 0 hours, when the time remaining should be 59:59, it says 1:-1:59?

Tags: python, time

This is meant to be a countdown timer, the user enters the hours, minutes, and seconds. However, if I enter more than 0 hours, when the time should be 59:59 after it used to be 1:00:00, it goes to 1:-1:59. Can anybody tell me why this is?

```
import time
from klaxon import klaxon, klaxonify
def countdown(h, m, s):
    while h or m or s != 0:
        if h != 0:
            hrs = h
            mins = m
            secs = s
            timer = '{}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hrs, mins, secs)
            klaxon(title = 'Countdown Timer', subtitle = 'Time remaining:', message = '{}'.format(timer), sound = False)
            print(timer)
            time.sleep(0.000001)
            if s != 0:
                s -= 1
            elif s == 0:
                m -= 1
                s = 59
            elif m == 0:
                h -= 1
                m = 59
                s = 59
        elif h == 0:
            mins = m
            secs = s
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            klaxon(title = 'Countdown Timer', subtitle = 'Time remaining:', message = '{}'.format(timer), sound = False)
            print(timer)
            time.sleep(0.00001)
            if s != 0:
                s -=1
            elif s == 0:
                m -= 1
                s = 59
    klaxon(title = 'Countdown timer is up!', message = 'Your countdown timer is up.', sound = True)
h = input('Enter the number of hours (if none, enter 0): ')
m = input('Enter the number of minutes (if none, enter 0): ')
s = input('Enter the number of seconds (if none, enter 0): ')
countdown(int(h), int(m), int(s))
```

Comment: Either `s` is not equal to zero, or it is equal to zero: there is no third choice.  So your `elif m == 0:` block of code can never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes for much simpler code to keep track of the total time in seconds, and then simply format it when you're printing it using modulo (`%`) and integer division (`//`).

```
def countdown(h, m, s):
    s += m * 60 + h * 3600         # Calculate total seconds
    while s:
        hh = s // 3600             # Calculate current hours
        mm = (s % 3600) // 60      # Calculate current minutes
        ss = s % 60                # Calculate current seconds
        if hh:
            print(f"{hh}:{mm:02d}:{ss:02d}")
        else:
            print(f"{mm:02d}:{ss:02d}")

        time.sleep(0.00001)
        s -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from time import sleep

time = timedelta(hours = 1, minutes = 0, seconds = 0)
_1second = timedelta(seconds = 1)

while (time - _1second).seconds != -1:
  time = time - _1second 
  print(time)
  sleep(1)
```

You can get the values for the hours, minutes and seconds from the user using `input()` after the import statements.

It's probably better to use builtin libraries for date and time stuff because there will be edge cases you will miss.